How to handle watch() with @input in vue
I want to handle a v-model change based on an @input variable update, but I'm facing issues with the order of "happenings" in vue. Here is a simplified version of my issue:
<script setup>
import { ref, watch } from 'vue'

const foo = ref(1)
const bar = ref(1)
const lorem = ref(false)

const handleInput = (val) => {
  bar.value = val
}

watch(foo, (newFoo) => {
  if (bar.value === 2) {
    lorem.value = true
  }
})
</script>

<template>
  <input v-model="foo" @input="handleInput(2)"><br>
  {{foo}}<br>
  {{bar}}<br>
  {{lorem}}
</template>

It seems, that the watcher hits before the handleInput method was executed.
If I change the value of foo in the input field, the lorem value will be set to true if I change the value of foo a second time, only. I want to set it to true immediately.
I tried to implement nextTick() and flush: 'post', but it does not have the expected result:
<script setup>
import { ref, nextTick, watch } from 'vue'

const foo = ref(1)
const bar = ref(1)
const lorem = ref(false)

const handleInput = (val) => {
  nextTick(() => {
    bar.value = val
  })
}

watch(foo, async (newFoo) => {
  await nextTick()
  if (bar.value === 2) {
    lorem.value = true
  }
}, { flush: 'post' })
</script>

<template>
  <input v-model="foo" @input="handleInput(2)"><br>
  {{foo}}<br>
  {{bar}}<br>
  {{lorem}}
</template>

Here is a Vue Playground showing my issue.

That you use v-model and raw events indicates a potential problem. It's either one or another. Can you clarify why you didn't just use v-model?

I have a calculator with multiple inputs. v-model sets the actual calculation value and @input sets the activeInput and depending on the activeInput the calculation is different. That's why I'm checking the activeInput (in the given example bar) in the watcher

What you do is undocumented and results in undefined behavior. You should just use v-model and do in watch(foo, everything handleInput was intended for. I don't see why this wouldn't work here. But if v-model doesn't work for you for some reason then desugar it to raw prop+event and don't use v-model at all.

Please read the docs: v-model on form elements is an alias for @input (or @change for selects) + :value (or :checked for checkboxes). When you use v-model you should not use @input, @change, :value or :checked, because they are ignored. If you want to execute code when the value changes, instead of placing the function on @input you execute it using watch of watchEffect.

Also, note you might be asking a XY problem question. Rather than asking how to modify Vue's behavior, you might want to ask how you can solve the real problem you're facing, which is not clear from the code you posted so far.

In the Vue's code there are "jobs" executed seemingly as microtasks and the DOM update following.
nextTick():

A utility for waiting for the next DOM update flush.

In our case the changing of an input value doesn't queue any DOM update so nextTick() is scheduled immediately as a microtask. Using 2 await nextTick(); also doesn't help... Neither {flush:post}...
So the solution is to use more a radical way to postpone the watch's code, setTimeout() comes to mind, but I've tried requestAnimationFrame and it works, I like it better because it allows execution right after all microtasks and before the page repaint.
Playground
But actually you don't need this trick, just place all of your logic inside handleInput:
Playground
<script setup>

import { ref, watch , reactive, nextTick} from 'vue'

const foo = ref(1)
const bar = ref(1)
const lorem = ref(false)
const log = reactive([]);

const handleInput = (val) => {
  bar.value = val
  lorem.value = bar.value === 2;
  log.push(`bar: ${val} lorem: ${lorem.value} foo: ${foo.value}`);
}

</script>

<template>
  <input v-model="foo" @input="handleInput(2)"><br>
  <input v-model="foo" @input="handleInput(1)"><br>
  {{foo}}<br>
  {{bar}}<br>
  {{lorem}}
  <div v-for="line in log">
    {{line}}
  </div>
</template>


You're right, thanks. That's a way I can go
